# How can I use Html Css & Javascript to create touch enabled image carousel that autoplays on page load

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a carousel controlled with radio buttons and triggered with data-attributes manipulated through javascript. I went through several attempts and iterations and with the help of responders, I have been able to make several changes that eventually got it to work. See updated attempt below. Please post any suggestions that can help make it even better or more efficient.

```html
    <div id="carouselWrapper">

      <div id="carousel-controls">
        <span class="control-icon" id="prev">⇦</span>
        <span class="control-icon" id="next">⇨</span>
      </div>

      <div class="carouselList">
        <div class="carouselListItem first">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/000000/FFFFFF/png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="carouselListItem second">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/000000/FFFFFF/png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="carouselListItem third">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/000000/FFFFFF/png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="carouselListItem fourth">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/000000/FFFFFF/png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="carouselListItem fifth">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/000000/FFFFFF/png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="navigation-container">
        <div class="radios">
          <input id="radio1" class="radTrigger" type="radio" name="radio-btn" data-index="0" value="radio1">
          <label for="radio1" class="radio-btn"></label>
          <input id="radio2" class="radTrigger" type="radio" name="radio-btn" data-index="1">
          <label for="radio2" class="radio-btn"></label>
          <input id="radio3" class="radTrigger" type="radio" name="radio-btn" data-index="2">
          <label for="radio3" class="radio-btn"></label>
          <input id="radio4" class="radTrigger" type="radio" name="radio-btn" data-index="3">
          <label for="radio4" class="radio-btn"></label>
          <input id="radio5" class="radTrigger" type="radio" name="radio-btn" data-index="4">
          <label for="radio5" class="radio-btn"></label>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <Script>
      window.onload = function carousel() {

        //CONTROLLING THE CAROUSEL WITH RADIO BUTTONS
        // Indexing
        const allRads = document.querySelectorAll(".radios > input[type='radio']");

        // Loop over all the carousel images
        const allImages = document.querySelectorAll(".carouselListItem");

        // Keep the first radio (Image 1) checked when the page loads
        document.querySelector('input[value="radio1"]').checked = true;

        // One event handler on radios (parent) to trigger the event
        document.querySelector(".radios").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
          // First, check to see if the event was triggered by an element we care to respond to:
          if (event.target.classList.contains("radTrigger")) {

            // Loop over all the elements and remove the active class from the relevant image and corresponding radio
            allImages.forEach(function(item) {
              item.classList.remove("activeListItem");
            });

            allRads.forEach(function(item) {
              item.classList.remove("activeRadio");
            });

            // Add the active class to the <div> who's index corresponds to the clicked radio button's index.
            allImages[Array.from(allRads).indexOf(event.target)].classList.add("activeListItem");
          }
        });
      }

      // Initialize the index
      let currentIndex = 0;
      const images = document.querySelectorAll('.carouselListItem');
      const radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="radio-btn"]');

      function updateCarousel(index) {
        images.forEach((image, i) => {
          if (i === index) {
            image.style.display = 'block';
            radios[i].checked = true;
          } else {
            image.style.display = 'none';
            radios[i].checked = false;
          }
        });
      }

      // How long the carousel will remain on each image (adjust as needed)
      function cycleCarousel() {
        currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % images.length;
        updateCarousel(currentIndex);
        setTimeout(cycleCarousel, 4000);
      }

      // Using radios to control what image is shown
      radios.forEach(radio => {
        radio.addEventListener('click', () => {
          const selectedIndex = parseInt(radio.getAttribute('data-index'));
          currentIndex = selectedIndex;
          updateCarousel(selectedIndex);
        });
      });

      const prevButton = document.getElementById('prev');
      const nextButton = document.getElementById('next');

      //Activating the control icons
      prevButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        currentIndex = (currentIndex - 1 + images.length) % images.length;
        updateCarousel(currentIndex);
      });

      nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % images.length;
        updateCarousel(currentIndex);
      });

      // Touch handling for swiping
      const carouselContainer = document.getElementById('carouselWrapper');
      let touchStartX = 0;
      let touchDeltaX = 0;

      carouselContainer.addEventListener('touchstart', e => {
        touchStartX = e.touches[0].clientX;
        touchDeltaX = 0;
      });

      carouselContainer.addEventListener('touchmove', e => {
        touchDeltaX = e.touches[0].clientX - touchStartX;
      });

      carouselContainer.addEventListener('touchend', () => {
        const threshold = 50; // Minimum distance for a swipe

        if (touchDeltaX > threshold) {
          currentIndex = (currentIndex - 1 + radios.length) % radios.length;
          updateCarousel(currentIndex);
        } else if (touchDeltaX < -threshold) {
          currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % radios.length;
          updateCarousel(currentIndex);
        }
      });

      //Controlling how long it takes the carousel to autoplay after the page loads
      window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        updateCarousel(currentIndex);
        setTimeout(cycleCarousel, 6000);
      });

    </Script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, I recommend checking out [mcve] and posting what you have tried. You are asked to at least make an attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to learn how to use Stack Overflow properly. We expect that you'll do your research and make an attempt at a solution before posting here. Then, when you do post, we expect that you'll post the code you have tried, along with details of what the problem is that you are facing. We are not a code writing service. Also, questions that ask for the "most efficient" or "best way" to accomplish something will likely get closed as being opinion based.

Comment: FYI: You are not using the [`data-` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) correctly. They should have a value and not simply have the attribute there without that. If you are just looking for a way to mark an element as active, you should be using CSS classes, rather than `data-` attributes.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your responses and the heads up. I've tried a bunch of things but i'll update my question now with the latest attempt.

Comment: For the snippet, I would probably try using a placeholder image like `https://placehold.co/100x100/000000/ffffff`. Since the image isn't the problem in question.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I created a carousel and wrote a function that changes the image to the previous or next based on which button is clicked. That's what the data-active attribute was for. Is that a bad idea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This question began with me trying to build a carousel controlled with radio buttons and triggered with data-attributes manipulated through javascript. With the help of responders and comments, I was able to get this done and more.

Below is a whittled down version of the code I used to get it done. I was also able to integrate touch handling so the carousel can be swiped for mobile-friendly uses. I welcome any corrections and I hope it saves someone the time I burned figuring these out.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Image Carousel</title>
    <style>
      .carouselWrapper {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        position: relative;
        margin: auto;
        place-content: center;
      }

      .carouselWrapper>div {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
      }

      .carouselListItem {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        margin: 0 auto;
        inset: 0;
      }

      .activeListItem {
        display: block;
      }

      .carouselListItem:first-child {
        display: block;
      }

      .carouselListItem>img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        object-position: center;
        pointer-events: none;
      }

      .navigation-container {
        z-index: 10;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        bottom: 9.65rem;
      }

      .control-icon {
        position: absolute;
        width: 0;
        opacity: 0;
      }

      .radio-btn {
        border: 2px solid rgb(0, 196, 196, 0.75);
        padding: 6px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 0.5s;
      }

      .radios input[type="radio"] {
        width: 0;
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0;
      }

      .radios .radio-btn:not(:last-child) {
        margin-right: 15px;
      }

      .radios input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
        background: rgb(0, 196, 196, 0.75);
        border: 2px solid rgb(0, 196, 196, 0.75);
      }

      .activeRadio {
        background: rgb(0, 196, 196, 0.75);
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="carouselWrapper">

      <div id="carousel-controls">
        <span class="control-icon" id="prev">⇦</span>
        <span class="control-icon" id="next">⇨</span>
      </div>

      <div class="carouselList">
        <div class="carouselListItem first">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/000000/FFFFFF/png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="carouselListItem second">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/000000/FFFFFF/png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="carouselListItem third">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/000000/FFFFFF/png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="carouselListItem fourth">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/000000/FFFFFF/png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="carouselListItem fifth">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/000000/FFFFFF/png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="navigation-container">
        <div class="radios">
          <input id="radio1" class="radTrigger" type="radio" name="radio-btn" data-index="0" value="radio1">
          <label for="radio1" class="radio-btn"></label>
          <input id="radio2" class="radTrigger" type="radio" name="radio-btn" data-index="1">
          <label for="radio2" class="radio-btn"></label>
          <input id="radio3" class="radTrigger" type="radio" name="radio-btn" data-index="2">
          <label for="radio3" class="radio-btn"></label>
          <input id="radio4" class="radTrigger" type="radio" name="radio-btn" data-index="3">
          <label for="radio4" class="radio-btn"></label>
          <input id="radio5" class="radTrigger" type="radio" name="radio-btn" data-index="4">
          <label for="radio5" class="radio-btn"></label>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <Script>
      //Carousel
      window.onload = function carousel() {

        //CONTROLLING THE CAROUSEL WITH RADIO BUTTONS
        // Indexing
        const allRads = document.querySelectorAll(".radios > input[type='radio']");

        // Loop over all the carousel images
        const allImages = document.querySelectorAll(".carouselListItem");

        // Keep the first radio (Image 1) checked when the page loads
        document.querySelector('input[value="radio1"]').checked = true;

        // One event handler on radios (parent) to trigger the event
        document.querySelector(".radios").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
          // First, check to see if the event was triggered by an element we care to respond to:
          if (event.target.classList.contains("radTrigger")) {

            // Loop over all the elements and remove the active class from the relevant image and corresponding radio
            allImages.forEach(function(item) {
              item.classList.remove("activeListItem");
            });

            allRads.forEach(function(item) {
              item.classList.remove("activeRadio");
            });

            // Add the active class to the <div> who's index corresponds to the clicked radio button's index.
            allImages[Array.from(allRads).indexOf(event.target)].classList.add("activeListItem");
          }
        });
      }

      // Initialize the index
      let currentIndex = 0;
      const images = document.querySelectorAll('.carouselListItem');
      const radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="radio-btn"]');

      function updateCarousel(index) {
        images.forEach((image, i) => {
          if (i === index) {
            image.style.display = 'block';
            radios[i].checked = true;
          } else {
            image.style.display = 'none';
            radios[i].checked = false;
          }
        });
      }

      // How long the carousel will remain on each image (adjust as needed)
      function cycleCarousel() {
        currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % images.length;
        updateCarousel(currentIndex);
        setTimeout(cycleCarousel, 4000);
      }

      // Using radios to control what image is shown
      radios.forEach(radio => {
        radio.addEventListener('click', () => {
          const selectedIndex = parseInt(radio.getAttribute('data-index'));
          currentIndex = selectedIndex;
          updateCarousel(selectedIndex);
        });
      });

      const prevButton = document.getElementById('prev');
      const nextButton = document.getElementById('next');

      //Activating the control icons
      prevButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        currentIndex = (currentIndex - 1 + images.length) % images.length;
        updateCarousel(currentIndex);
      });

      nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % images.length;
        updateCarousel(currentIndex);
      });

      // Touch handling for swiping
      const carouselContainer = document.getElementById('carouselWrapper');
      let touchStartX = 0;
      let touchDeltaX = 0;

      carouselContainer.addEventListener('touchstart', e => {
        touchStartX = e.touches[0].clientX;
        touchDeltaX = 0;
      });

      carouselContainer.addEventListener('touchmove', e => {
        touchDeltaX = e.touches[0].clientX - touchStartX;
      });

      carouselContainer.addEventListener('touchend', () => {
        const threshold = 50; // Minimum distance for a swipe

        if (touchDeltaX > threshold) {
          currentIndex = (currentIndex - 1 + radios.length) % radios.length;
          updateCarousel(currentIndex);
        } else if (touchDeltaX < -threshold) {
          currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % radios.length;
          updateCarousel(currentIndex);
        }
      });

      //Controlling how long it takes the carousel to autoplay after the page loads
      window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        updateCarousel(currentIndex);
        setTimeout(cycleCarousel, 6000);
      });

    </Script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your still using `data-` attributes, element `id`s, and classes to specifically identify individual elements, none of which are necessary here.

Comment: @ScottMarcus when I take out the radio Ids and data-indexes the radio just doesn't work. Could you please point out where the error(s) is/are.

Comment: Please see the second code sample in my answer as I've added a working solution that shows how to avoid all of these things.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having multiple change events, I'm using a forEach loop on querySelectorAll looking for all radio-buttons.

On each radio button I have a data-target attribute that corresponds to a matching data-id attribute on a div holding an image. I prefer this over IDs as IDs can get messy.

In my event handler, I look for the radio button that was changed (via ev.target).

I also look for anything that already has activeRad. If that exists, I remove that class so we don't have duplicates.

Then I simply use the target from the data-target to find the div to add the activeRad class to.

Then at the very end I check to see if any divs already have the activeRad class. if so, take that div's id and check the radio that has the matching data-target.

I chose to use a single class instead of inactive and active as inactive can be achieved by targeting the .listItem in CSS.

```js
const radios = document.querySelectorAll(".radio-button");

const handleRadio = (ev) => {
  const radio = ev.target;
  const hasActive = document.querySelector(".activeRad");
  if(hasActive)hasActive.classList.remove("activeRad");
  
  const target = document.querySelector("[data-id='" + radio.dataset.target + "']");
  target.classList.add("activeRad");
}

radios.forEach((r) => r.addEventListener("change",handleRadio))

const hasActive = document.querySelector(".activeRad");

if(hasActive){
  const target = document.querySelector("[data-target='" + hasActive.dataset.id + "']");
  target.checked = true;
}
```

```css
.listItem{
  border:4px solid transparent;
  display:inline-block;
}

.listItem.activeRad{
  border-color:#ff0000;
}
```

```html
<!-- Radio buttons -->
<div class="radio-inputs">
  <input class="radio-button" data-target="1" type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio1">
  <input class="radio-button" data-target="2" type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio2">
  <input class="radio-button" data-target="3" type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio3">
</div>

<!-- Carousel -->
<div class="list" data-slides>
  <div data-id="1" class="listItem first ">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/000000/ffffff" alt="">
  </div>
  <div data-id="2" class="listItem second activeRad">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/000000/ffffff" alt="">
  </div>
  <div data-id="3" class="listItem third">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/000000/ffffff" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @imvain2. Your comments and snippet were very helpful.

Comment: The use of data- attributes to change visual aspects of the page goes against separation of concerns and what data- attributes were designed for. CSS is for managing presentation. data- attributes are for managing, well data. Incorporating data- attributes for this just adds complexity where none is needed.

Comment: Cheers @ScottMarcus. I'll keep that in mind for better practice.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `data-` attributes here (and [you are not using them correctly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)). Instead, CSS classes are the way to go.

Also, the use of `id` attributes, while simple enough, leads to brittle code that doesn't scale easily. In most cases, you don't need them though because there are several other ways to get element references (as you can see below).

By avoiding the use of `id` and by setting up just one event handler that can handle `click` events from any element within it, the code below is very scalable. If you need to add more radio buttons and images, just update the HTML accordingly and you won't need to touch the JS at all. :)

There's no need for an `inactive` class as an element becomes inactive as soon as the `active` class is removed from it.

See comments inline below for details:

```js
// If you do need element references, get them just once (outside of the function)
// rather than every time the function is called.
// .getElementsByClassName() returns a live node-list of all
// matching elements. It's an old API that is resource intensive
// and should be avoided.

// This will be used for indexing purposes
const allRads = document.querySelectorAll(".radios > input[type='radio']");

// This will be used to loop over all the div elements
const allDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".listItem");

// Set up just one event handler on the parent of the items
// that could trigger the event
document.querySelector(".radios").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  // First, check to see if the event was triggered by an element
  // we care to respond to:
  if(event.target.classList.contains("radTrigger")){

    // Loop over all the elements and remove the active class
    allDivs.forEach(function(item){
      item.classList.remove("active");
    });
  
    // Add the active class to the <div> who's index corresponds to the clicked
    // radio buttton's index.
    allDivs[Array.from(allRads).indexOf(event.target)].classList.add("active");
  }
});
```

```css
/* Style this however you want, but classes are the way
   to go here, not data- attributes. */
.active { border:2px solid red; }

/* This is just for better visualization here at SO */
.list > .listItem { display:inline-block; }
```

```html
<!-- Since the JS doesn't rely on data- attributes or id's
     you can see that it is much cleaner and doesn't require them. -->

<!-- Radio buttons -->
<div class="radios">
  <input class="radTrigger" type="radio" name="radio-btn">
  <input class="radTrigger" type="radio" name="radio-btn">
  <input class="radTrigger" type="radio" name="radio-btn">
</div>

<!-- Carousel -->
<div class="list">
  <div class="listItem">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/000000/FFFFFF/png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="listItem">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/000000/FFFFFF/png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="listItem">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/000000/FFFFFF/png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Now that I see a bit better what you are after, see the snippet below and note that `id`s, `data-` attributes, and classes that indicate what number each radio button is are not needed.

If you ever want to add more images and radio buttons, you just add them according to the pattern established in the HTML and no adjustments to the JavaScript or CSS are needed. And, the HTML is much cleaner, making it so much simpler to read and understand. This is what scalability means and you rarely achieve this with `id`s, `data-` attributes and classes acting as `id`s.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Image Carousel</title>
  <style>
    .carousel-container {
      position: relative;
      max-width: 100vw;
      margin: 0 auto;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .carousel {
      display: flex;
      transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .carousel-slide {
      flex: 0 0 100%;
    }
    
    .carousel-image {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
    
    .radio-buttons {
      position: absolute;
      z-index:999;
      bottom: 20px;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      display: flex;
    }
    
    .radio-button {
      appearance: none;
      width: 12px;
      height: 12px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: 2px solid #555;
      margin: 0 5px;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: transparent;
    }
    
    .radio-button:checked {
      background-color: #555;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="carousel-container">
    <div class="carousel">
      <!-- If you ever want to add more images, just add another <div><img></div> in the carousel
           and another corresponding <label><input type="radio"></label> in the radio-buttons area. -->
      <div class="carousel-slide">
        <img class="carousel-image" src="https://placehold.co/50x50/000000/FFFFFF/png" alt="Image 1">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-slide">
        <img class="carousel-image" src="https://placehold.co/50x50/000000/FFFFFF/png" alt="Image 2">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-slide">
        <img class="carousel-image" src="https://placehold.co/50x50/000000/FFFFFF/png" alt="Image 3">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="radio-buttons">
      <label><input type="radio" class="radio-button" name="carousel-radio" checked></label>
      <label><input type="radio" class="radio-button" name="carousel-radio"></label>
      <label><input type="radio" class="radio-button" name="carousel-radio"></label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    const carousel = document.querySelector('.carousel');
    const carouselSlides = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-slide');
    const radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.radio-button');
    let currentIndex = 0;
    const numSlides = carouselSlides.length;

    function scrollToIndex(index) {
      currentIndex = index;
      const offsetX = currentIndex * -100;
      carousel.style.transform = `translateX(${offsetX}%)`;
      radioButtons[currentIndex].checked = true;
    }

    function autoScroll() {
      currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % numSlides;
      scrollToIndex(currentIndex);
    }

    const autoScrollInterval = setInterval(autoScroll, 3000);

    for (let i = 0; i < radioButtons.length; i++) {
      radioButtons[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        clearInterval(autoScrollInterval);
        scrollToIndex(i);
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "You shouldn't be using data- attributes here" I have a differing opinion for "toggles" myself.

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss  There is no intrinsic connection between data- attributes and styles, so you propose that creating a connection between these two disparate things makes sense? CSS classes are for exactly this purpose and no artificial connections needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to toggle classes as others suggest if all you want to do is change some CSS, you can use the data attribute and value.

Now, you want to add another one you don't need to change code just add elements with the right values.  As a bonus the new guys target selector can be anything that works AND even have different active style!

```js
let radioT = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio'][name='radio-btn']");

function handleEventFun(event) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.listItem')
    .forEach(el => el.dataset.active = "false");
  let v = this.value;
  let radtarg = document.querySelector(v);
  radtarg.dataset.active = "true";

  /* this works but is a lot of code when you add conditions for all of them */
  /*
    let first = document.querySelector(".first");
    let second = document.querySelector(".second");
    let third = document.querySelector(".third");
    first.classList.toggle('activeRad',v ==='.first')
    first.classList.toggle('inactiveRad',v !=='.first')
    second.classList.remove("activeRad");
    third.classList.remove("activeRad");
    radtarg.classList.add("activeRad");
    ...need more code to handle it all
    */
}
radioT.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', handleEventFun));
```

```css
/* works to start */

.listItem[data-active] {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: orange solid 1px;
}

.listItem[data-active="true"] {
  background-color: blue;
  border: solid red 2px;
}
.listItem[data-active="true"][data-iam="newguy"] {
    border: double purple 2px;
    padding: 1em;
    filter: saturate(50%);
}

.listItem[data-active="false"] {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<!-- Radio buttons -->
<div class="radio-inputs">
  <input class="radio-button" type="radio" name="radio-btn" value=".first">
  <input class="radio-button" type="radio" name="radio-btn" value=".second">
  <input class="radio-button" type="radio" name="radio-btn" value=".third">
  <input class="radio-button" type="radio" name="radio-btn" value=".listItem[data-iam='newguy']">
</div>

<!-- Carousel -->
<div class="list" data-slides>
  <div class="listItem first" data-active="true">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/000000/FFFFFF/png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="listItem second" data-active>
    <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/000000/FFFFFF/png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="listItem third" data-active>
    <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/000000/FFFFFF/png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="listItem" data-active data-iam="newguy">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/000000/FFFFFF/png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *if all you want to do is change some CSS, you can use the data attribute and value* <-- You *can*, but you shouldn't. If you want to change some CSS, use CSS and classes because that's exactly what they were designed to do. `data-` attributes were designed as a way for HTML developers to create valid HTML when a custom attribute would be helpful to store more, well, data along with the element. It's sometimes a blurred line, but this use case screams CSS, not `data-`.